# Setting header to the Calculation sum

Tags: tabulator

I'm using Tabulator 4.9. I set up a table with topCalc:sum.
Now I want to add on a column that has no calculation a text stating "Sum".
I can do that by modifying the cell with the text using Javascript.

Once I edit a field value of o cell in tried to use the cellEdited callback to handle the recalculation. But apparenty the sum is written after this callback to the table and my text disapears.

Is there a way to get hold of the topCalc and add the text afterwards?

| User | id | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sum |  | 20 |
| user1 | 1 | 10 |
| user2 | 2 | 10 |

after editing it looks like

| User | id | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | 25 |
| user1 | 1 | 15 |
| user2 | 2 | 10 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so if I understand you correctly (without any code examples to go by) you *ARE* using topCalc:"sum" on your field:"score" column, and want to put the string "Sum" in the topCalc aread of your field:"user" column ?

If so, look at [Custom Calculator Functions](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/column-calcs#func-custom) for your field:"user", just return the string "Sum"

Comment: Hi Michael, 

thanks for pointing me to the correct direction. That was exactly what I was looking for.